# Got an issue when i set calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to set a time is in between two time range, so I get current time , set first time and second time to compare .

But I find that the value of DAY_OF_MONTH is strange. Why does it show wrong value? 
Some one can teach me how to fix it?

```
    // load current time
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

    //set first time
    Calendar firstLimit= Calendar.getInstance();
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.MONTH,4);
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,8);
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

    //set second time
    Calendar secondLimit= Calendar.getInstance();
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.MONTH,4);
    firstLimit.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,12);
    secondLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
    secondLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    secondLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);

    //Wed May 10 06:14:04 GMT+00:00 2017
    Log.d("MONTH: current>",current.getTime()+"");
    //Fri May 12 12:30:30 GMT+00:00 2017  --> i thought it should be May 8
    Log.d("MONTH: firstLimit>",firstLimit.getTime()+"");
    //Wed May 10 12:30:30 GMT+00:00 2017 --> i thought it should be May 12
    Log.d("MONTH: secondLimit>",secondLimit.getTime()+"");
```

Comment: Look at your code.  You have confused `firstLimit` and `secondLimit`.

Comment: Yes , i want to use `if (current.after(firstLimit)  && current.before(secondLimit)) { }` , but the time range is wrong.

Comment: `firstLimit.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,12)` ... do you not see this?

Comment: oh god , i'm stupid... thanks for your reminding....:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting firstLimit after line -> //set second time

Replace firstLimit with secondLImit

```
//set second time
Calendar secondLimit= Calendar.getInstance();
secondLimit.set(Calendar.MONTH,4);   //replaced firstLimit with secondLImit
secondLimit.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,12); //replaced firstLimit with secondLImit

secondLimit.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
secondLimit.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
secondLimit.set(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
```

Comment: Typically we don't answer typo questions.  Just for future reference.